# How can I modify the 221 Statuscode-Message in Postfix?

Tags: configuration, smtp, email

As stated in the title i would like to modify the `221 (QUIT SMTP)` Statuscode Message from my Postfix MTA.

I've recently seen a good example when i tested Mailgun.org at [checktls.com](http://www.checktls.com/perl/TestReceiver.pl) saying:

```
221 See you later. Yours truly, Mailgun
```

Postfix at default settings says: `221 2.0.0 Bye`

So how do I accomplish to set a custom `Quit SMTP` message in Postfix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one way: **patch sources**. Quit reply is hardcoded.

You need `quit_cmd` function in [src/smtpd/smtpd.c](https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/master/postfix/src/smtpd/smtpd.c)